# Use multiple SSH keys with VSTS

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops

I am trying to figure out how to use multiple SSH keys with VSTS. I have two different VSTS accounts and an SSH key associated with each. As long as I only add one key to the SSH-Agent at a time, I can connect to the repos for that account fine. Once I add both keys to the agent however, I will always get a login failure for the second account as it will use the first account's key. I thought this might be behavior related to SSH on Windows but I get the same behavior on OSX as well.

`>git clone ssh://account2@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22/DefaultCollection/_ssh/your-repo
Cloning into 'your-repo'...
remote:
remote: Your Git command did not succeed.
remote: Details:
remote:         Public key authentication failed.
remote:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

The relevant part of my .ssh/config currently looks like the following. I've messed around with the host values but nothing I've tried has made a difference.

```
Host account1@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
    Hostname vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
    User account1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_account1_vsts
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UpdateHostKeys yes

Host account2@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
    Hostname vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
    User account2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_account2_vsts
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UpdateHostKeys yes
```

Comment: What if you use a different name for Host? like a1 and a2? `git clone a2:DefaultCollection/_ssh/your-repo`: that will guarantee to actually use your ssh config file.

Comment: It was not apparent from everything that I found on SSH and Git that the host was an alias for the URL that should be used as opposed to just some sort of unique identifier for the config entry. I had a ton of entries in my config but they were all for different hosts so I never had to make this mental leap. Thanks for the missing piece @VonC.

Comment: Wait... I would have posted it as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure the etiquette here. You were first at the basic info but @starian chen-MSFT was the first with a very clear and complete answer.

Comment: Just a simple copy of my comment, never mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t use such value as Host, replace it like this:

```
Host hostaccount1
        Hostname vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
        User account1
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_account1_vsts
        AddKeysToAgent yes
        UpdateHostKeys yes

   Host hostaccount2
        Hostname vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
        User account2
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_account2_vsts
        AddKeysToAgent yes
        UpdateHostKeys yes
```

Then, you can clone the repository like this

`git clone ssh://hostaccount2:22/_ssh/{repo}`

`git clone ssh://hostaccount1:22/_ssh/{repo}`

(replace `account1@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com` to `hostaccount1`, same as `hostaccount2`)

Comment: So... what I just commented?

Comment: There is one piece that is missing from this answer that I recently learned is needed. You should also add IdentitiesOnly yes to each AzDOS host entry. Otherwise it's possible that cached credentials for another host could be used first, causing a connection error.